# I've never heard that song

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/i-have-never-seen-him-that-drunk-vs-i-had-never-seen-him-that-drunk?reply=663495676387475976#663495676387475976

From the link, I become curious whether the following sentence a) implies ones with before or by now.

> (a) I've never heard that song.
>
> (a1) I've never heard that song before
>
> (a1) I've never heard that song by now

Comment: Your third example is syntactically invalid. Normally the first one would only be said ***if it is still true*** (which it obviously ***wouldn't*** be if you were actually listening to the song at time of speaking). So for most contexts, your version #2 would be the correct one.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Hello, If I say, `I have heard that song by now`. In that case, it would be possible? So whether "by now' or "before" could come along with "have P.P" is up to sentence's style - declarative sentences or negative sentences, couldn't it?

Comment: It's almost impossible to devise a context where *I have heard that song by now* would be a valid utterance. You probably mean *I have heard that song **before*** or *I have **already** heard that song* (which for most purposes are equivalent and interchangeable). Note that there are often many ways of saying exactly or approximately the same thing in English. Your second example above, for example, could be changed to *I haven't **ever** heard it before*, making it more obvious that (optional) ***ever*** just adds emphasis (same as your ***I've never*** instead of ***I haven't***).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I have learned more.of thing. Yeap. So do you mean also using"have P.P" with "by + time noun" ? For example) `I have done the project by this Friday. (X)`. I had better say the thing like this. `I did the project this Friday.`

Comment: *I have done the project by this Friday* doesn't make sense to me. I assume "this Friday" is *in the future* at time of speaking. If the person was *speaking* on Friday, having completed the work a couple of days earlier, it's very unlikely he would include the word ***this*** when saying *I did the project by Wednesday.* Note that we only normally use ***by*** in such contexts if there was extreme time pressure to complete a job ***by*** some deadline (and even then, *I finished it by Wednesday* is unlikely compared to *I finished it **on** Wednesday* unless it was finished ***very early***).